# C# Object Duplication In List

Tags: c#, list, random

I am trying to create a simple simulation using a list of objects and making it perform a calculation repeatedly to represent a farmer. It has one method which increases the amount of money the farmer has by a random percentage and each farmer starts with $100

```
    public class Farmer
    {
    public decimal money { get; set; }

    public Farmer()
    {
        money = 100;
    }

    public void doOneYear() //Represents how much money the farmer earned
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        decimal growth = random.Next(0, 100);
        decimal percentage = (growth / 1000);
        money = money * (1 + percentage);
    }
}
```

The code which runs is this

```
        List<Farmer> farmers = new List<Farmer>();

        int count = 0;

        while (count < 10)
        {
            Farmer newFarmer = new Farmer();
            farmers.Add(newFarmer);
            count++;
        }


        foreach(var farmer in farmers)
        {
            int years = 0;
            while (years < 10)
            {
                farmer.doOneYear();
                years++;
            }
        }


        foreach (var farmer in farmers)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(farmer.money.ToString());
        }
```

However the results I get back is just the first object in the list repeated. If I step through the whole process in debug mode it works fine but when I let it run the objects appear to be duplicated.

Comment: i think your random is returning the same number.did you check whether the random is returning a new growth every time

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random number generator only generating one random number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the program runs so quickly, and I believe the Random class uses a time setting as its default seed, you need to inject a seed yourself into the Random call. (This is also likely why you would see different numbers when debugging - you made the program run slower, therefore the Random class would output different numbers).

I did it like this, and saw a different number for each farmer in the output.  You may want to use a different seed generation though.

```
    public class Farmer
    {
        private static int seed = 17;

        public decimal money { get; set; }
        public int FarmerID { get; set; }
        public Farmer(int id)
        {
            money = 100;
            FarmerID = id;
        }

        public void doOneYear() //Represents how much money the farmer earned
        {
            seed++;
            Random random = new Random(seed);
            decimal growth = random.Next(0, 100);
            decimal percentage = (growth / 1000);
            money = money * (1 + percentage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a compile-time const for seed will cause the program to give the same random value for each run. A static/global/passed-to-constructor Random-instance is normally a better way to go at it (unless having the same result each time is what you want).

Comment: Note that my code shown increments the seed before it is used.  I actually ran the code, and it gives different numbers for the farmers.  That said, as I noted in my answer, he should consider a different seed generation - my simplified answer was merely intended to answer his asked question.

Comment: Yes, they will give different numbers for each farmer, but if you run the program 10 times, farmer 1 will always have the same number as he did the other 9 times (as will farmer 2 and 3 etc.). That's the reason for using time in seed (which is what the default-constructor do). You could simply change the seed to be something time-based like `private static int seed = DateTime.Now.Milliseconds;` to achieve this though.

Comment: Agreed, as noted this isn't an ideal seed generation.  But that's a separate question if the OP chooses to ask it.

Comment: I didn't stop to think about how the random value was being generated, I was thinking I was doing something wrong with lists and going crazy.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:  "The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers."

I'd just make the Random instance a static member, personally:

```
public class Farmer
{
    public decimal money { get; set; }
    private static Random random = new Random();

    public Farmer()
    {
        money = 100;
    }

    public void doOneYear() //Represents how much money the farmer earned
    {
        decimal growth = random.Next(0, 100);
        decimal percentage = (growth / 1000);
        money = money * (1 + percentage);
    }
}
```